# Interacting with Non-academics: How to Not Compromise One's Rigor?

Tags: interpersonal-issues, communication, social-skills, science-communication

This is a question about interacting with other people (in particular, non-academics). Hopefully, this is a common-enough problem that it is appropriate for this community.

I consider myself an (aspiring) academic, and I have very strong beliefs (about my academic field (mathematics), how one does work, etc). At the same time, I acknowledge that everybody is different, and that people have ways of doing things that "work for them." I am also aware of my own ignorance (or at least, I think I am).

A.) That being said, I have a very hard time listening to people who (I believe) are wrong (or at the very least, are using very, very bad arguments). By being complacent with their opinions, I feel like I am compromising my own integrity. I am also worried that this complacency will condition me to condone such ideas, and ultimately, make me a less virtuous person.

B.) On the other hand, many people do not like to be told they are wrong (either factually, or that they are using faulty arguments). Many self-help books, psychology articles, and people around me suggest that often, one must "agree to disagree" with such people. Moreover, I am told that likable people can provide information that other people want to hear. (This makes a lot of sense in view of human nature.)

I feel very conflicted in engaging in the behavior described in B, as I feel like I am compromising my own integrity (in the sense described in A). Indeed, the people in my life who I respect the most (many of whom are academics) are those who are capable of telling me bad news, and who help me have a better understanding of the world and reality.

**My Question.** How should one engage in conversation with other people (in particular, nonacademics) while not compromising academic rigor (too much) and still being reasonably likable? (Here, "reasonably likable" means not losing the most important people (family, close friends, etc.) in one's own social circle.)

I find it hard to believe that I am the only person who has this problem. Many academics I know are as adamant about their opinion as I am (if not more), and many of them seem to have  trouble interacting with other people. Thus, I would like to ask for the community's thoughts.

One possible answer to my problem is, "choose carefully who to pick fights with," i.e. if one's audience is not someone who cares about academic inquiry, then I should not try to engage in a rigorous discussion with said person. However, I am dissatisfied with this solution because, as I said, I am a.) concerned that this compromises my integrity, and b.) I would condition my self to be complacent with bad arguments.

Comment: "By being complacent with their opinions, I feel like I am compromising my own integrity."  This is wrong.  You are not responsible for other people's opinions unless you taught them.

Comment: Maybe try https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Academic rigor" has nothing to do with what you describe as such.

Comment: So you like to argue and feel you have to be ‘right’? Nothing to do with academic rigor.

Comment: I mean, in your profile you state that you like to be an internet troll (“like to ask dumb questions to generate discussion,” or such). First part of that mission accomplished.

Comment: It seems like people are concerned with the exact terminology I used here. ("Academic rigor.") Without attacking my particular word choice (I will try to be more careful next time), can people try to address the core of my question? (I think it's clear what I am trying to ask since I got some good answers from people.)

Comment: @gnomertorule I mean, what I meant in the profile is "I like to use Stackexchange to ask questions I am too afraid to ask people in real life." My intention was never to be an "internet troll" as you say (although yes, I see how it can be misinterpreted now; I will change it).

The term "dumb question" is not used pejoratively, as one can see from the quotes in my profile.

Comment: Don't get into arguments about mathematics at parties.  For everything else, remember that you're no more an expert than they are.

Comment: It seems like you have an issue thinking of yourself as being wrong and others as being right. Everyone in my department doesn't have "trouble interacting with other people." I'm also confused about what you mean by "opinions," do you mean opinions about scientific things, or harmful opinions like opposing equal rights?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rigor is not the same as pedantery. It is a category of thinking, not of using formalism. The argument of "integrity" is pure smokescreen. It's hard to communicate with the appropriate level of simplification to non-scientists without compromising the essence, but it does not mean that one should not try.

One special facet of this issue, which is particularly salient at present times, are superstitions or conspiracy theories (which may be quite harmless if annoying in general, but can cause extended damage in the case of vaccinations, ecological or economical decision-making but have more to operate on because of the associated uncertainties in the fields). These are again a separate category of thinking. These have a lot to do with ideological thinking. This is territory where opinions are agenda- and attitude-driven and factual arguments won't get you very far. Usually, there is little one can do here, especially if a debate is laced with rhetorics and political slogans devoid of factual foundation, but full of innuendo, identity groups or dog whistling.

As a scientist, if one wishes to persist in such environments, the main lesson is a Socratic one. Let go of the desire to educate these people of your scientific knowledge and begin learning: why do they have this opinion, what can you learn from that? Not about reality, but about the picture of reality that these people create for themselves and where it comes from.

Maybe you can sow the seed of scientific thinking, namely the idea of doubt.  Doubt as a method is central to science, and a scientific statement always (ok, almost always ;-) requires qualification (I am aware that in mathematics it's less so, but see the various discussions on axiomatization). If it's not qualified (at least in principle), it's a belief, not a scientific statement. This is in the same category as falsifiability, but the latter is harder to explain.

I recommend reading Feynman. He discusses these issues at length. He tried precisely to bridge this gap and loved interacting with non-academics. He is well known for his successes in communication to nonscientific public. One thing he emphasizes is an almost Socratic method of "thinking and experimenting for oneself". One of his legendary demonstrations was the inflexibility of the O-ring of the Space Shuttle when cooled to freezing temperature.

Other than that, there is nothing virtuous in imposing your (even scientific) belief on others; it's tolerance that is a virtue. "You can only show them the door. They are the ones that have to walk through it." [adapted from The Matrix]

As long as a disagreeable opinion does not cause harm to people, you can just let it go.

If it does, it ceases being a scientific discussion and becomes a political one. But that's a separate story.

Comment: I agree with your answer. One caveat about doubt, though: Conspiracy ideologues "doubt" all kinds of things a reasonable person believes or has trust in. Of course, they are highly biased in what they doubt and what they believe in. It's probably a good idea to try to make them see that a) in fact they hold a lot of unquestioned beliefs, b) skepticism "all the way to the bottom" leads to an infinite regress, so some reasonable assumptions (shared by people outside their own belief system) are indispensible.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica You are of course right. There is the "doubt" that serves to pave way for an agenda, and there is the philosophical doubt of infinite regress (which is different from the agenda-driven doubt) and they are different from my list; I might think of how to rephrase it more carefully. Basically, I refer to the Cromwell-type doubt.